# Forward Backward filter Scipy - $\tt signal.filtfilt$ changes the amplitude when $\tt signal.butter$ is used with $\tt btype='high'$

Tags: filters, python, lowpass-filter, highpass-filter, scipy

In the plot below the blue wave is the original signal. The orange wave is after the low pass filter. The green wave is after the high pass filter.
[image: The blue wave is the original signal. The orange wave is after the low pass filter. The green wave is after the high pass filter]

I have a noisy ECG signal stored in the `ecg_val` column of a pandas dataframe. I'm doing the following:

```
# implement the 30 Hz low-pass forward-backward filter
__nyq = 0.5 * self.resample_frequency
__normal_lowpass_cutoff = self.lowpass_cutoff / __nyq
__order = 5
b, a = signal.butter(__order, __normal_lowpass_cutoff, btype='low')
self.ecg['ecg_val'] = signal.filtfilt(b, a, self.ecg['ecg_val'])

plt.plot(self.ecg['hexoskin_timestamps'], self.ecg['ecg_val'])

# implement the 1.4 Hz high-pass forward-backward filter
__nyq = 0.5 * self.resample_frequency
__normal_highpass_cutoff = self.highpass_cutoff / __nyq
__order = 2
b, a = signal.butter(__order, __normal_highpass_cutoff, btype='high', analog=False)
self.ecg['ecg_val'] = signal.filtfilt(b, a, self.ecg['ecg_val'])

plt.plot(self.ecg['hexoskin_timestamps'], self.ecg['ecg_val'])

plt.show()
```

As you can see, the application of the *low-pass forward-backward* filter doesn't change the amplitude of the original signal. But the *high-pass forward-backward* filter begins at 0 - which I wouldn't want happening.

How do I change this?

The `Scipy` implementation of `filtfilt` from [here](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/signal/signaltools.py) is as follows

```
def filtfilt(b, a, x, axis=-1, padtype='odd', padlen=None, method='pad'):
    b = np.atleast_1d(b)
    a = np.atleast_1d(a)
    x = np.asarray(x)

    # method == "pad"
    edge, ext = _validate_pad(padtype, padlen, x, axis,
                              ntaps=max(len(a), len(b)))

    # Get the steady state of the filter's step response.
    zi = lfilter_zi(b, a)

    # Reshape zi and create x0 so that zi*x0 broadcasts
    # to the correct value for the 'zi' keyword argument
    # to lfilter.
    zi_shape = [1] * x.ndim
    zi_shape[axis] = zi.size
    zi = np.reshape(zi, zi_shape)
    x0 = axis_slice(ext, stop=1, axis=axis)

    # Forward filter.
    (y, zf) = lfilter(b, a, ext, axis=axis, zi=zi * x0)

    # Backward filter.
    # Create y0 so zi*y0 broadcasts appropriately.
    y0 = axis_slice(y, start=-1, axis=axis)
    (y, zf) = lfilter(b, a, axis_reverse(y, axis=axis), axis=axis, zi=zi * y0)

    # Reverse y.
    y = axis_reverse(y, axis=axis)

    if edge > 0:
        # Slice the actual signal from the extended signal.
        y = axis_slice(y, start=edge, stop=-edge, axis=axis)

    return y
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your signal has a DC offset, i.e. its average is non-zero (approximately $1$ in this case). This component is captured by the 0'th frequency bin. So if a high-pass filter is applied to the signal, all components below the cut-off frequency (1.4 Hz) will be removed, including the DC one (0 Hz).

In general, you should always remove the mean of your signal before performing any sort of analysis. I am not sure about ECG applications, but it should be no different. Please try to remove it from both blue and orange signal.

A slight off-topic, but there are very narrow filters which are designed to specifically remove the 0 Hz component. For example you can read more about them [here](http://www.embedded.com/design/configurable-systems/4007653/DSP-Tricks-DC-Removal) and [here](https://www.dsprelated.com/showarticle/58.php).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60271/discussion-on-answer-by-jojek-forward-backward-filter-scipy-signal-filtfilt-ch).